# Django TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django, url, model, view

Ok so I have a project called tvlistings and an app called progguide.

In my tvlistings directory I have the following in these files

settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/home/paul/tvlistings/progguide/templates',
)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^progguide/', include('progguide.urls')),
)
```

In my progguide directory I have

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('progguide.views',
    (r'^$', 'index'),
    (r'^(?P<prog_id>\d+)/$', 'programme'),
)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from progguide.models import *

def index(request):
    chan_prog_list = ChannelProgramme.objects.all().order_by('progdate','starttime')[:5]
    return render_to_response('progguide/index.html', {'chan_prog_list': chan_prog_list})
```

And in /home/paul/tvlistings/progguide/templates I have

index.html

```
{% if chan_prog_list % }
    <ul>
    {% for prog in chan_prog_list %}
        <li>{{ prog.channelid.channelname}} {{ prog.programmeid.progtitle }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No programmes.</p>
{% endif %}
```

If I try to load http://localhost:8000/progguide I get

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /progguide/
>
> progguide/index.html
>
> Request Method:  GET Request URL:
>    http://127.0.0.1:8000/progguide/
>   Django Version:  1.2.4 Exception Type:
>    TemplateDoesNotExist Exception Value:
>
> progguide/index.html

Still very new to this, the above looks ok from what I understand. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close though it's actually supposed to be

```
return render_to_response('index.html', {'chan_prog_list': chan_prog_list})
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing the templates folder?
You can use:

```
return render_to_response('progguide/templates/index.html', {'chan_prog_list': chan_prog_list})
```

Answer (score 1):

The string you pass to `render_to_response` is the relative path to the template, starting from any of the values you have given in TEMPLATE_DIRS. So, given what you have in that setting, you should just use `render_to_response('index.html' , ... )`.