# django TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django

I want to make a signup page, when user click signup, it will check if the two password are the same, when not, give a error message after "confirm password".

But when I call "return render(request, reverse("accounts:signup"), {'form': signup_form}) " in my views.py, it shows me an error, the traceback is:

```
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signup_post/

Django Version: 1.7
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'accounts')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')

Template Loader Error:
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:

Traceback:
File "/Users/feizhao/.virtualenvs/nahan/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/feizhao/dropbox/nahan/accounts/views.py" in signup_post
  64.     return render(request, reverse("accounts:signup"), {'form': signup_form})
File "/Users/feizhao/.virtualenvs/nahan/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  48.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs),
File "/Users/feizhao/.virtualenvs/nahan/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  170.         t = get_template(template_name, dirs)
File "/Users/feizhao/.virtualenvs/nahan/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template
  144.     template, origin = find_template(template_name, dirs)
File "/Users/feizhao/.virtualenvs/nahan/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in find_template
  136.     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/signup_post/
Exception Value: /accounts/signup/
```

my account app looks like:

```
$ tree -L 3 accounts
accounts
├── __init__.py
├── admin.py
├── forms.py
├── locale
│   └── zh_CN
├── migrations
│   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   ├── __init__.py
├── models.py
├── static
│   └── accounts
│       └── login.css
├── templates
│   └── accounts
│       ├── base.html
│       ├── login.html
│       └── signup.html
├── tests.py
├── urls.py
├── views.py
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls', namespace="accounts")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

accounts/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^login/$', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^signup/$', views.signup, name='signup'),
    url(r'^login_post/$', views.login_post, name='login_post'),
    url(r'^signup_post/$', views.signup_post, name='signup_post'),
)
```

signup_post function in views.py:

```
def signup_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        signup_form = forms.SignupForm(request.POST)

        if signup_form.is_valid():
            signup_info = signup_form.cleaned_data
            username = signup_info['username']
            email = signup_info['email']
            password = signup_info['password_1']
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                username=username,
                email=email,
                password=password)
            user.save()

    else:
        signup_form = forms.SignupForm()

    return render(request, reverse("accounts:signup"), {'form': signup_form})
```

I have read [Django TemplateDoesNotExist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765003/django-templatedoesnotexist) and other similar questions, but no help!

ps: I have asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27821252/django-form-field-validation-and-error-display) about the signup, maybe usefull.

Comment: What does your `signup` view look like? What are your rendering to in that view?

Comment: `reverse("accounts:signup")` returns an url, not a template name, try `return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'form': signup_form})`

Comment: @abidibo that is correct, you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that

```
reverse("accounts:signup")
```

returns an url, see here (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse), while you need a template path, so you should return:

```
return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'form': signup_form})
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the template dir path in your setings.py file, 
Please paste the code below in you settings.py file.

```
import os

PROJECT_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH,'templates'),
)
```

As well as you have to pass the template name in the view when you return the response.

```
return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'form': signup_form})
```

Comment: `accounts` is an installed app, as you can see from the trace, and since `django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader` is enabled there is no need (in this case) to add the TEMPLATE_DIRS tuple in the settings.py

Comment: TEMPLATE_DIRS is to guide django to search for templates in that particular path which you specify in this tuple. Rest "accounts/signup.html" argument which you pass in the "render" function depends how you store your html files under your "templates" folder. So ideally in this case your html file should reside under "templates/accounts/signup.html"

Comment: yes, but dealing with the original question, from the app tree you can see that the `signup.html` template is inside the templates folder of the app, so it is found by the `django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader`. For this reason in this case there is no need to specify the TEMPLATE_DIRS tuple.

Comment: @abidibo: Yes, I agree with you looking again to the directory structure which is displayed in the question, we would not need to define the TEMPLATE_DIRS tuple. But I use to follow this approach from the time I use to follow Django 1.3, that was the reason I mentioned to define the TEMPLATE_DIRS tuple.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that reverse() function returns url (from urls.py). So args to render() looks like this:

```
return render(request, '/signup/', {'form': signup_form}) # look at 'singup' path at url.py
```

You have to hardcode path to template.

```
return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'form': signup_form})
```